# Why is tornado self.post finishing with a call to self.get?

Tags: python-3.x, post, get, tornado, redirect

I've inherited a Python tornado project. I'm not super familiar with Tornado.

The problem is; when a call to classname.post is complete, the python attempts to redirect to a webpage. On that webpage, clicking OK then redirects to another page.

However, when you click OK on the browser (to trigger the redirect in the HTML/JS), Tornado instead calls the classname.get() method and does not go to the redirect.

** Application **

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/internal/meta_(\w\w\w\w\w\w\w$)", InternalMetaHandler),
            (r"/", WelcomeHandler),
            (r"/input_data", InputHandler),
            (r"/external/meta_(\w\w\w\w\w\w\w$)", ExternalMetaHandler),
            (r"/static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,
             {"path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("overview.html")), "static/")}),
        ]

        settings = dict(
            debug=True,  # TODO SWITCH OFF!!! autoreload server when changes are detected
        )

        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```

** InputHandler **

```
class InputHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, MetaD):

    def get(self):
        log.debug("IN InputHandler.get()...")

    def post(self):
        log.debug('post input received')
        # Parse the data passed in from the form dict            
        data_from_web = self.request.arguments.get("slug")[0]  # load data                 
            # This works
        <open file for read>
            # This works
        <open file for write>
            # This works
        <Try to update GIT>
            # This fails so we update the messages
            feedback_title  = "There were errors..."
            feedback_string = "FILE UPLOAD(s): (Nothing to upload)<BR>DATA CHANGES: OK<BR>GIT UPDATE: failed! (No error message) Files will be pushed on next run when git is available."

        self.render("static/InputHandlerComplete.html", received_title = feedback_title, received_message=feedback_string)
        # ALSO TRIED
        # self.redirect("static/InputHandlerComplete.html", received_title = feedback_title, received_message=feedback_string)
```

** InputHandlerComplete.html **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Metadata-Feedback</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .container {
            width: 500px;
            height: 50%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>{% autoescape None %}{{received_title}}</h1>
        {% autoescape None %}{{received_message}}
        <form>
            <button id="myButton" >OK</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
                    location.href = "http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/external/meta_7699587";
                };
            </script>
        </form>        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

** Sending form to POST results in the correct InputHandlerComplete.html page**
[image]


** Clicking OK within InputHandlerComplete.html does NOT go to the link in the HTML code, but instead goes to to InputHandler.get() (see the blank page image below, and the log) **
[image]

**log**

```
("Submit" button to the form was pressed here. Data is sent as a "POST")

[D 180403 12:44:51 loghandler:795] post input received
[D 180403 12:44:51 loghandler:795] (new_output_data) Opening '/home/metadata/metadata-prototype/implementation/server/../../metadata/projects/mirko_test_aff1f69/mirko_test_aff1f69.json' for read  ...OK
[D 180403 12:44:51 loghandler:795] (new_output_data) Opening '/home/metadata/metadata-prototype/implementation/server/../../metadata/projects/mirko_test_aff1f69/mirko_test_aff1f69.json' for write ...OK
[D 180403 12:44:51 loghandler:795] Updating GIT...
[D 180403 12:44:51 loghandler:795] GIT return code was '1'
[D 180403 12:44:51 loghandler:795] (No error message)
[D 180403 12:44:51 loghandler:795] GIT UPDATE: failed! (No error message)
     Files will be pushed on next run when git is available.
[D 180403 12:44:51 loghandler:795] (new_output_data) Opening '/home/metadata/metadata-prototype/implementation/server/../../metadata/projects/mirko_test_aff1f69/mirko_test_aff1f69.json' for write ...OK
[I 180403 12:44:51 web:2064] 200 POST /input_data (172.16.168.1) 30.21ms

(OK BUTTON ON THE "There were errors..." REDIRECT PAGE WAS CLICKED HERE)

[D 180403 12:45:25 loghandler:795] IN InputHandler.get()...
[I 180403 12:45:25 web:2064] 200 GET /input_data (172.16.168.1) 1.64ms
```

Comment: This is more of a browser question than a Tornado question. The `<form>` submits as a GET request to the current URL, since the Javascript doesn't explicitly prevent it.

Comment: OK. Makes sense. So, when I click the "send" button, it hits the Tornado server as a post and that all gets processed. THEN it again hits the server as a get. If this is something in the HTML/JS code - I'd happily accept changes to that as an answer. Do you have suggestions how I can correct the page code?

Comment: Try removing the `<form>`. You don't need it.